# What javascript MATH.PI MATH.SQRT really does?

Tags: javascript

```
var a=Math.sqrt(0);
var b=Math.sqrt(1);
var c=Math.sqrt(9);
var d=Math.sqrt(64);
var e=Math.sqrt(-9);
```

I do not quite understand what does `Math.PI` and `Math.sqrt` exactly?

Comment: have you tried outputting the answers to see what they give?  It seems quite obvious by their names.

Comment: Where do you want to Google today?

Comment: What do you expect from a function called "squareroot" and a constant named "Pi"?

Comment: Also you can check MDN when in doubt - [`Math.sqrt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt), [`Math.PI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/PI)

Answer (score 1):

[Math.PI](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.1.6) accesses a variable which represents the value 3.141...

[Math.sqrt(x)](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.17) finds the square root of x

Comment: Now that Bergi added the ECMA links, it made me wonder if JS implementations actually output a different result for `+0` and `-0`.

Answer (score 1):

The names are somewhat self explanatory. `Math.PI` is a constant which holds the value of [pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) (i.e. `3.14...`). `Math.sqrt` determines the [square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root) of its argument.

Taking the square root of a negative value (`-9`, for instance) will result in [`NaN`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.23) because, in reality, you cannot express the square roots of negative numbers in terms of real numbers.